# How to recognize "a grammar is an OPG" without building precedence matrix?

Tags: parsing, grammar, operator-precedence

Given a grammar that satisfies the following two conditions,

1. No adjacent non-terminals
2. No rules in the form "S -> epsilon"

We can recognize that such grammar is an Operator Precedence Grammar (OPG) by building the precedence matrix, if for each terminal pair, there is at most one relation (<, = or >).

Then, is there another way to recognize that such grammar is (not) an Operator Precedence Grammar without building the precedence matrix?

Comment: Building the precedence matrix takes O(|G|). It's hard to see any motivation to seek a different solution :) (And I don't believe there is one which is fundamentally different from constructing the matrix.)

Comment: Thanks. I also cannot find another answer from literatures.